# how to loop through a function into method call in python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I am trying to make a simple function to python kafka and I am having trouble on passing a loop of string into the producer.send_messages method.

```
from kafka import SimpleProducer, KafkaClient
import random
import os

kafka = KafkaClient('localhost:9092')
producer = SimpleProducer(kafka)
x = 0

while x!=1:
        #producer.send_messages(b'test1',b'str(i)') #the program will run with this type of input
        a=random.random()
        message_method= "b"+"'"+topic+"'"+","+"b"+"'"+str(a)+"'"
        producer.send_messages(message_method)
```

I will end up with this error,

```
 File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kafka/producer/simple.py", line 52, in send_messages
    partition = self._next_partition(topic)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kafka/producer/simple.py", line 36, in _next_partition
    self.client.load_metadata_for_topics(topic)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kafka/client.py", line 378, in load_metadata_for_topics
    kafka.common.check_error(topic_metadata)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kafka/common.py", line 233, in check_error
    raise error_class(response)
kafka.common.UnknownError: TopicMetadata(topic="b'test1',b'0.595202345912'", error=17, partitions=[])
```

I appreciate any advice to make this into a more dynamic way( no need to hard code b'messages'...etc) to put messages into kafka too. :D

Comment: Why did you split your string into single-character strings and then concatenate them? Anyway, the "modern" way to write that line is `message_method = "b'{}',b'{}'".format(topic, a)`.

Comment: Yea, that still did not work , error   <br/> `File "simpleproducer.py", line 11, in <module>
    producer.send_messages(message_method)
 ...   kafka.common.check_error(topic_metadata)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kafka/common.py", line 233, in check_error
 raise error_class(response)
kafka.common.UnknownError: TopicMetadata(topic="b'test1,b'0.23424'", error=17, partitions=[])`

Comment: Oh, I don't know what's causing the error - I just wanted to give you a much cleaner way to write that string. What you have there now is the equivalent of `print('h'+'e'+'l'+'l'+'o'+' '+'w'+'o'+'r' +'l'+'d')`.

Comment: Yea, I was doing it 'cavemen', but totally appreciate your suggestion though:).

Answer (score 0):

You should use send_message function this way :

`producer.send_messages('test1', str(a))`

I think it is more appropriate.

Comment: It needs to put a byte `producer.send_messages(b'test1',b'str(i)')'`notation in front of every parameter due to the fact it has byte transmission and this cause formatting in the entry weird.